# angularjs: invoke creates new services

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, requirejs

I have a big list of a services and controllers that are created when the website first loads and then I call angular.bootstrap. Then, later I would like to run some arbitrary code that can be dependency injected. The way I do this is by creating a function, specifying it's dependencies with annotations, getting the injector for the module I was using, and then calling invoke on that function.

I use requirejs to load this plugin and any other plugin so that is what is being returned out of the module. the code looks like this

```
define [
    'scripts/inherits/basePlugin'
] , (BasePlugin) ->
    # The explicit block lists the angular services/factories you need
    # all game logic/entity classes go inside this block
    explicit = (Options, Renderer) ->
        class Checkers extends BasePlugin.Plugin
            constructor: () ->
                super()
                @checkersOptions = [
                    [
                        "checkbox",
                        "test checkbox",
                        false
                    ],
                    [
                        "slider",
                        "test slider",
                        0, 3, 1
                    ],
                    [
                        "textbox",
                        "test textbox",
                        "this is some text"
                    ],
                    [
                        "dropdown",
                        "test dropdown",
                        ["blah", "blah2", "blah3"],
                        "blah2"
                    ]
                ]
                Options.addPage "Checkers", @checkersOptions

            selectEntities: (renderer, turn, x, y) ->

            verifyEntities:(renderer, turn, selection) ->

            getName: () -> 'Checkers'

            predraw: (turn, dt, renderer) ->

            postdraw: (turn, dt, renderer) ->

            resize: (renderer) ->

            loadGame: (@gamedata, renderer) ->

            getSexpScheme: () -> null

        return Checkers

    # the dependencies are manually injected here
    explicit.$inject = ['Options', 'Renderer']
    $injector = angular.injector(['webvisApp'])

    # the constructor function for the main checkers object is returned here
    return $injector.invoke(explicit)
```

Now at the end, i'm trying to return the class prototype for 'Checkers' here that has access to angular services 'Options' and 'Renderer'. At the end when I call invoke, it runs without complaint but for some reason the two services are re-instantiated, as in the constructors for those two services are invoked again, obliterating any data that they previously had. Why does invoke cause these services to be recreated?

EDIT:
SOLUTION: Turns out the injector function creates new injectors instead of using the one in your module. my solution was this:

```
# make your module
webvisApp = angular.module 'webvisApp', [
    'ngCookies'
    'ngSanitize'
    'ngRoute'
    'ui.bootstrap'
]

# attach injector to publicly accessible member
webvisApp.run ($injector) ->
    webvisApp.injector = $injector

# create your controllers and services

# bootstrap the application
angular.bootstrap document, ['webvisApp']
```

Then to invoke some function with dependencies:

```
needsDependencies = (Renderer, Options) ->
   #do stuff

needsDependencies.$inject = ['Renderer', 'Options']
webvisApp = angular.module('webvisApp')
webvisApp.injector.invoke needsDependencies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating new injector instance with `angular.injector`, and it differs from the one that you've got with `angular.bootstrap` elsewhere. Each of these injector instances creates its own service instances.

I'm not quite sure about application architecture, but I guess that you have to provide an injector from bootstrapped application to all modules.

Comment: That was it. Don't quite understand what the use case for making a new injector like that is, but whatever. During a run block on the module, after bootstrapping and all the providers are made, I attach $injector onto the module, like webvisApp.injector = $injector. and then I was able to inject abritrary functions like webvisApp.injector.invoke funcName. Worked like a charm. Thanks!